# How do I turn my navigation into a mega menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, navigation

I'm useless with JS/jQuery so need some help turning my menu into a browser compatible / responsive mega menu. I REALLY DON"T want to use a massive plugin for this because what I want is pretty simple and don't want to impact page load for the worse.

On page load I just want 'Open Menu' visible, when 'Open Menu' is clicked i'd like to show the `ul#expanded` and hide the 'Open Menu' link. Then, when 'Close Menu' is clicked I'd like it to hide `ul#expanded` and show 'Open Menu' again. Nothing fancy at all.

I have been playing around with jQuery `toggle` but haven't been successful. I've put my HTML/CSS here: http://jsfiddle.net/YrTMm/

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: JSfiddle javascript field is empty. Did you link the right one?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp good study

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Yeah I had pasted the wrong link with the missing toggle script. Completely my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'll throw you a bone since it looks like you actually did try a couple things. You can easily do this by attaching a click handler and using jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` methods.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Set up a quick reference to the element.
    var el = $("#expanded");
    //Hide the element by default.
    el.hide();
    //Add a click handler to the 'open' link.
    $("#open").click(function(){
        //Check if the expanded menu is visible.
        if(el.is(":visible")){
            //If it is, hide it.
            el.hide();
        }else{
            //If not, show it.
            el.show();
        }
    });
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YrTMm/1/)

Comment: Thanks for throwing that bone. Thats just what I was looking for. Really appreciate it. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

here's another way you could accomplish this.  (using css & a touch of jquery)

http://jsfiddle.net/CSmg7/

first, you can simplify your navigation some (yes i know you need real things in the UL), also, it's invalid to have an anchor as a direct child of a ul, it should be contained in a list item, or outside of the ul. your better bet may be to use a  or  for your menu

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="open toggleMenu">Open Menu</a><a href="#" class="closed toggleMenu">Close Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

just use js to add a class to the parent:

```
$("#nav")
.on("click", ".toggleMenu", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $(this)
  .parent()
   .toggleClass("open");
});
```

and add a little css to make your jquery work:

```
#nav li ul,
#nav li .toggleMenu.closed,
#nav li.open .toggleMenu.open{
display: none;
}
#nav li.open ul,
#nav li.open .toggleMenu.closed{
display: block; /*or whatever you need*/
}
```

then you can have multiple menus if you need that will just work